# XSLT 1.0 Substring from right side of string

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a value in an element as 433554567643.
I would like to change it to 43 35545 67643. The grouping should start from right side of the value.
Is it possible to use subtring from end to start of the value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a recursive template.

```xslt
<xsl:template name="add-spaces">
  <xsl:param name="group" select="5" />
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:if test="string-length($text) &gt; $group">
    <xsl:call-template name="add-spaces">
      <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group" />
      <xsl:with-param name="text"
              select="substring($text, 1, string-length($text) - $group)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, string-length($text) - $group + 1)" />
</xsl:template>
```

You would call this when required using

```xslt
<xsl:call-template name="add-spaces">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'433554567643'" />
  <!-- or select="path/to/element" as appropriate -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: @user1441279 glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ it by clicking on the tick mark to the left.  This shows others at a glance that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. I just ticked that. I will keep that in mind for future. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2):

If your value is always a number, you could use [`format-number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number) with a pattern that groups the numbers by 5 digits and then [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate) the "," into " ":

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number('433554567643', '#,#####'), 
                                ',', ' ')" />
```